# Count Entries from ArrayField or Datagrid in React-Admin

Tags: react-admin

How can i count and output the length of an array field as a textfield or numberfield?

Code of the ArrayField that works and outputs a DataGrid

```
               <ArrayField source="re_benutzers">
                    <Datagrid>
                        <TextField source="vorname" />
                    </Datagrid>
                </ArrayField>
```

Source: (from Strapi)

```
 {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "sdf",
    "re_benutzers": [{
        "id": 1,
        "vorname": "Something",
    },
```

^this can hold multiple entries and i want to output the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a custom component for that instead of the DataGrid.

ArrayField will inject all ids retrieved in a list context.
So you can do something like:

```js
const LengthField = (props) => {
    const { ids, loaded } = useListContext(props);
    
    return loaded ? ids.length : null;
};
// And then
<ArrayField source="re_benutzers">
    <LengthField />
</ArrayField>
```

Comment: thank you - this worked!

const LenghtField = () => {
    const { data, ids } = useListContext();
    return ( <Chip align="center" label={ids.length}></Chip> );
};

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the FunctionField component:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#functionfield:

```
<FunctionField label="Count" render={record => `${record?.re_benutzers?.length ?? ""}`} />
```